# JMETER 5.1.1 : Merge identical samplers from the same session (as with JMETER 3.2)

Tags: jmeter

I have just upgrated from JMETER 3.2 to JMETER 5.1.1.

I have a problem in generating the JTL file.

To run a test, I use the following command:

```
& .\jmeter.bat -n -t "C:\test\jmx_test.jmx" -l "C:\test\jmx_test.jtl" -j "C:\test\jmx_test.txt"
```

Before, with version 3.2 the result of the JTL was :

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1568895933205,686,000_Login - /test-app,200,OK,Declaration_1... 1-1,text,true,,3170,314,1,1,685,0,650
1568895935077,312,001_Login - /test-app/login/login.jsf,200,OK,Declaration_2... 1-1,text,true,,11873,1025,1,1,212,0,0
....
```

Now with version 5.1.1, the result is :

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1568897692191,669,000_Login - /test-app,200,OK,Declaration_1... 1-1,text,true,,3168,314,1,1,https://xxxxx.jsf,668,0,637
1568897693648,260,001_Login - /test-app/login/login.jsf,200,OK,Declaration_2... 1-1,text,true,,11871,1041,1,1,https://xxxxx;jsessionid=xxxx,199,0,0
1568897693648,199,001_Login - /test-app/login/login.jsf-0,302,Moved Temporarily,Declaration_2... 1-1,text,true,,407,655,1,1,https://xxxxx;jsessionid=xxxx,199,0,0
1568897693852,56,001_Login - /test-app/login/login.jsf-1,200,OK,Declaration_2... 1-1,text,true,,11464,386,1,1,https://xxxxx;jsessionid=xxxx,55,0,0
....
```

As next I create reports with this command :

```
& ./CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --input-jtl "C:\test\jmx_test.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport --generate-csv jmx_test.csv
```

I have problems because the samplers are duplicated.
With version 5.1.1, is it possible to merge, as before, the 3 labels of the same sampler (001_Login - /test-app/login/login.jsf / 001_Login - /test-app/login/login.jsf-0 / 001_Login - /test-app/login/login.jsf-1) ?

In advance, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a redirection happening and in your HTTP sampler and "follow redirection" option is checked. Uncheck it and check "redirect automatically" and run it again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I change this result, it may change the result from what I have read (http://www.testingdiaries.com/difference-between-redirect-automatically-and-follow-redirects/).

I think I've found the solution.
I have changed the value of the "subresults.disable_renaming" property in the "jmeter.properties" file :

```
# Since version 5.0 JMeter has a new SubResult Naming Policy which numbers subresults by default
# This property if set to true discards renaming policy. This can be required if you're using JMeter for functional testing.
# Defaults to: false
subresults.disable_renaming=true
```

What do you think about that?